# SAXParser - Escaping Special Characters

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

I am parsing the below string using SAXParser

`<xml>
<FirstTag>&amp;&lt;</FirstTag>
<SecondTag>test</SecondTag>
</xml>`

I want the same string to be retained but it is getting converted to below

`<xml>
<FirstTag>&<</FirstTag>
<SecondTag>test</SecondTag>
<xml>`

Here is my code. How can I avoid this being converted?

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
        MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();  
        values = handler.getValues();
        saxParser.parse(x, handler);
```

Comment: &lt; is what you write in XML to mean `<`, because `<` must be escaped (same for `&amp;`). If you want to output those chars somewhere and escape them again, then use an XML marshaller that will do it automatically, or escape them by yourself explicitely. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to pass this output to another service. That service seems to accept the values in the form of these characters rather than xml tags.

Comment: Then escape them. A service that takes non-XML as input but expects characters to be escaped as if it was XML looks like a badly-designed service to me.

Comment: This is why you should use XML APIs to write XML out as well as to parse it in. They will take care of escaping for you, automagically. If you insist on hand-coding your XML serializations, it will be your responsibility to re-implement that logic.

Comment: the service takes xml as input. In one specific xml tag , there is a huge string and that has characters like &lt; &gt; etc which needs to be retained. The SAXParser converts these into xml tags as well.

Comment: I have now updated my example

Comment: Working exactly as designed. The XML parser takes XML as input and delivers the semantic content of that XML, which is the value after escapes and entitites have been resolved. That's what the document's author wanted you to have; that's what you want to have. No problem on that end of things.

Comment: In order to retain the characters in FirstTag element , what should I do?

Comment: You've shown partial code that parses the xml input, and no code that produces output.  We need to see more in order to help.  Please consider making a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/).